# Callback instead WebBrowser - Android Twitter

Tags: java, android, twitter

As I think my question is not well understood I will change

Apparently the app works but doesn't redirect correctly so I get this "page not available" error. I'm not sure where is the problem exactly, as the app is not giving any exception or error when getting the requestToken.

[image: error]

Here is the code in the async method:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        Log.i("onPostExecute", "finish...");
        if (pDialog != null) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
    }
}
```

When the application authenticates twitter should send my app again but directed me to the callback url address. Do not know what to do to return to my application.

Comment: Have you added `Internet` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in android manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have them in the code.

Comment: I see my problem, it is on callback_url, I have:

`static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "app://twitter";`

What URL do I need in order to post tweets from my app?

Comment: Okay, so whether it solved or not?

Comment: No, what you told me wasn't the solution.

Comment: I know that was not the problem, but generally i am asking whether you solved the problem or still you are finding difficulty.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed the URL from callback for "http://twitter.com" but the app redirects me to official twitter when I wanted to lead me to:

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));`

Comment: I didn't get you properly what exactly you are trying to say.

Comment: When I change the URL of the constant call callback_url application takes me to that page, but I want to redirect me to the window of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added below permissions in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

define callback_url = " app://exampleTwitter and then put in Manifest.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="exampleTwitter"
            android:scheme="app" />
    </intent-filter>
```

This code redirect correctly to Callback Url instead Web Browser